# Codeigniter - uri routing, skipping a segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'd like to skip a section of a uri with Code Igniter. I have the following urls

```
/about
/info
/admin/users
/admin/pages
/admin/pages/edit/123
```

However I'd like to skip admin when searching for the class, i.e. the default config acts like this:

```
/admin[class]/pages[function]/edit[var]/123[var]
```

However I'd like it to work like this:

```
/admin[skip]/pages[class]/edit[function]/123[var]
```

Unfortunately I can't just start my application one level deeper as I have top level pages too.

I'd rather not add a rule for every page if I don't have to.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your controllers into subdirectories a single level deep in codeigniter out of the box.

so your directory structure would be

```
/application
    /controllers
        /admin
            pages.php [pages class]
```

Answer (score 2):

@jonjdavidjohn's suggestion should work, but there is another option if you don't go that way.

In config/routes.php re-route all /admin/requests to the appropriate controller:

```
// if you use this structure: controllers/pages.php
$route[admin/(:any)] = '$1';
```